# Host.net core application not working - This page can’t be displayed

Tags: iis, .net-core

I got the aplication for deploy to the server(Windows server 2016). The app is written in .NET Core 2.1 (I know, pretty old, but not my decision).

When I try to "browse" the appliacation, IE shows me only "This page can’t be displayed".

In LOG folder (./logs) is always something like this:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxx
Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:33860
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Application is shutting down...
```

In system logs (Event viewer) there isn'nt any helpfull information.

When I try to run application manually from CMD (dotnet MyApp.dll) it runs and seems good.
When I try to run over the IIS i got only the message above.

I tried to create new project app (also net core 2.1) and create new website in IIS it works good, but my application over the iis not working.

Any idea please?

//EDITED:

my hostbuilder:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
          //  .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")
            //.CaptureStartupErrors(true);
    }
```

Comment: Run some basic diagnostics and see what the report says, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: Seems like your host is built using `Kestrel` and you're running it on IIS. Can you share your `hostbuilder` code?

Comment: @MuhammadHannan do you think this code? I put it into first post.

Kestrel is linked in csproj file, but it seems it is never used

Comment: Yes, can you try `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseIISIntegration().UseStartup<Startup>();`

Comment: @MuhammadHannan still same ..

Comment: @LubosMarek Have you installed dotnet-core-hosting ??

Comment: @MuhammadHannan : yes, from this page https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1 I downloaded hosting Bundle

Comment: Have you provided permission for IIS to access the publish folder?

Comment: Did you deploy the web application via VS web deployment tool? It seems that you are using out-of process model to host your web application. So have you created 33860 for your IIS server? If you are hosting with http, you may need need to create a http binding with 33860 port. If you are hosting it with https, then you may have to create https port binding. Please remember to set application pool identity to unmanaged code

Comment: Hi, all of you, very thanks for your advices. The only error was, that the application was configured for https and i set up the http. So I deleted this rows (app.UseHttpsRedirection();  app.UseHsts();) - only for now and the app runs over the http. Everything is working now. I have to set the https and generete certificate and everything will be ok. Very thank you again.